# Show that there exists $20 \leq m, n \leq 5000$ so that the starting six digits of $2^m$ and $3^n$ are within 1 of each other.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

This question is from an old exam in a problem-solving course.

> Show that there exists $20 \leq m, n \leq 5000$ so that the starting six digits of $2^m$ and $3^n$ are within 1 of each other.

I'm not entirely sure where to begin with this question. I'm definitely thinking there should be a number theory argument here using modular arithmetic but not sure how to construct one. The starting 6 digits imply that the powers would have to be very large and to examine those digits I guess, I'd be looking at the values mod 10 but I'm not certain how to begin such an approach.

Any assistance with this problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the “starting digits” the “small ones” (aka ones, tens, hundreds, etc) or the “big ones” (leftmost)?

Comment: I'm assuming the leftmost. This was a past exam question and that was all the detail they provided

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Of the successive rational convergents to log 3/log 2, the last whose numerator is less than $5000$ is $1054/665$, and this should be a good one because the next convergent's numerator is 23 times larger: 24727. $2^{1054}=193025...$; $3^{665}=193034...$ with a difference of 9. So exactly what should be within 1 of each other is not clear.